# Cygwin aliases run different command when using special characters on Windows

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, notepad++, alias

- OS: Windows 10
- App: PHPStorm
- CLI: Cygwin (bash)
- Editor: Notepad++

My aliases don't run as they should.
Since short commands run fine, I'm guessing that this has to do with the use of special characters.

*C:\Cygwin\home\me\.profile*

```
alias symclear='bin/console cache:clear'
alias symdbcreate='php bin/console doctrine:database:create'
alias symdbfill='php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction'
alias symdbupdate='php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force'
alias syment='php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity'
alias syminfo='bin/console config:dump-reference'
alias symroute='bin/console debug:router'
alias symrun='php bin/console server:run'
alias symtest='./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit'
alias symbehat='/vendor/bin/behat features/'
```

terminal

```
$ php bin/console server:run

[OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000 

// Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

$ symrun

" is not defined.  un
```

Comment: what you used to write `.profile` ? what is the output of `file .profile` ?

Comment: alias symrun='php bin/console server:run'... wait, there are actually more of them. I'm going to check which one is wrong.

Comment: Looks like they all need semicolons at the end of line for starters. Adding semicolons is giving me `bash: $'\r': command not found` messages though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++

```
Settings -> Preferences -> New Document/Default Directory
 -> New Document -> Format -> Unix
```

*C:\Cygwin\home\me.profile*

```
alias symclear='php bin/console cache:clear';
alias symdbcreate='php bin/console doctrine:database:create';
alias symdbfill='php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction';
alias symdbupdate='php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force';
alias syment='php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity';
alias syminfo='php bin/console config:dump-reference';
alias symroute='php bin/console debug:router';
alias symrun='php bin/console server:run';
alias symtest='./bin/phpunit';
alias symbehat='/vendor/bin/behat features/';
```